# What are reasons a git pull command may return "fatal:" with no additional output (not even a newline)?

Tags: git, gitolite

I am trying to pull a git repo from a gitolite server.

`git pull` (and `git pull origin master`) both return the error "fatal:" with no additional output, not even a newline.  The ssh keys seem to be working properly as git clone and git fetch both function normally.

The error is particularly perplexing because it is not a new repo.  I have been pushing and pulling without the error in the past and the .git/config file has not changed.  I cannot think of any changes to my system since it was operating properly.

How can I obtain more diagnostic information to try to understand what is going wrong?  The lack of a newline made me suspect a timeout, but it is strange that git clone and git fetch still work.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour with a new repository?

Comment: Yes.  I have reproduced it with old and new repositories.  I also know it can't be related to a merge conflict because the fatal error happens when I try to git pull a newly cloned repo.  The expected behavior would be for git to print "Already up-to-date."

Answer (score 2):

Call `git pull` with the verbose `-v` flag. Also do `set GIT_TRACE=1` and try the pull command. These two should lead you towards the problem.

Comment: `GIT_TRACE=1 git pull -v` yields  
trace: exec: 'git-pull' '-v'  
trace: run_command: 'git-pull' '-v'

Comment: Just to be clear, the output consisted of the two "trace: ..." lines followed by "fatal:" as before.